# Search inside multidimensional array and return other key value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following 
[Multidimensional array.](http://bit.ly/1N4AVsA)

What I'm trying to do is to search for an IDITEM value and if it's found, return the value of the "PRECO" key.

I'm using the following function to check if the value exists and it works fine, but I can't find a way to get the "PRECO" value of the found IDITEM.

Function:

```
function search_array($needle, $haystack) {
 if(in_array($needle, $haystack)) {
      return true;
 }
 foreach($haystack as $element) {
      if(is_array($element) && search_array($needle, $element))
           return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```

Anyone can help me with that?

Comment: please update the output of the link to `var_export($array);` so it could be used

Comment: Ok I just changed the output

Comment: if var_export not working than just use echo "<pre>"; before print_r

Comment: @devpro you can simply go for the source code and extract the array, or simply read it there :) (I said source code, not inspect)

Comment: ahan @mloureiro: how stupid i am... :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the first if statement to return it instead of returning a boolean :

```
function search_array($needle, $haystack) {
    if(in_array($needle, $haystack) && array_key_exists('PRECO', $haystack)) {
        return $haystack['PRECO'];
    }
    foreach($haystack as $element) {
        if(is_array($element))
        {
            $result = search_array($needle, $element);
            if($result !== false)
                return $result;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. =)
There are other solutions over here that also works fine but I guess that's the easiest one. THANKS!!!!

Comment: @fackz: well i suggest u to dont forget to appreciate others if other's solution also working.. because they deserve it. :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest idea I can remember is converting that boolean `search_array` into a path creator, where it will return the path for the item, or *false* if it isn't found.

```
function get_array_path_to_needle($needle, array $haystack) 
{
  if(in_array($needle, $haystack)) 
  {
    return true;
  }

  foreach($haystack as $key => $element) 
  {
    if(is_array($element) && ($path = get_array_path_to_needle($needle, $element)) !== false)
    {
      return $path === true ? $key : $key . '.' . $path;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Then, since you already have the path, then rerun the array to fetch the item

```
function get_array_value_from_path(array $path, array $haystack)
{
  $current = $haystack;
  foreach($path as $key) 
  {
    if(is_array($current) && array_key_exists($key, $current))
    {
      $current = $current[$key];
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return $current;
}
```

This wont get you the PRECO, but it will return the item (array) where id found the value you searched for.

So a simple usage would be:

```
$path = get_array_path_to_needle('000000000000001650', $data);
$item = get_array_value_from_path(explode('.', $path), $data);
// here you have full array for that item found
print_r($item);
// here you have your price
print_r($item['PRECO']);
```

Comment: This solution also works fine, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use a `static` variable to remember the *status* between multiple function calls, and also to store the desired PRECO value. It makes the function remember the value of the given variable (`$needle_value` in this example) between multiple calls.

So your `search_array()` function should be like this:

```
function search_array($needle, $haystack){
    static $needle_value = null;
    if($needle_value != null){
        return $needle_value;
    }
    foreach($haystack as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            search_array($needle, $value);
        }else if($needle == $value){
            $needle_value = $haystack['PRECO'];
            break;
        }
    }
    return $needle_value;
}
```

This function will finally return `$needle_value`, which is your desired PRECO value from the haystack.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use a `foreach` loop twice.  Check for the key and store the result into an array for later use.

Based on your array, the below

```
$search = '000000000000001650';

foreach($array as $element){
    foreach ($element['ITEM'] as $item){
        if (isset($item['IDITEM']) and $item['IDITEM'] == $search){
            $results[] = $item['PRECO'];
        }
    }
}

print_r($results);
```

Will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 375
)
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for but also worked and helped! Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple example with array:

```
// your array with two indexes
$yourArr = array(
        0=>array(
                'IDDEPARTAMENTO'=>'0000000001',
                'DESCRDEPT'=>'Área',
                'ITEM'=>
                array(
                    array(
                        'SETID'=>'RX',
                        'IDITEM'=>'000000000000001367',
                        'DESCRITEM'=>'PISTA TESTE DRIV',
                        'PRECO'=>'1338.78'),
                    array(
                        'SETID'=>'RX',
                        'IDITEM'=>'000000000000001925',
                        'DESCRITEM'=>'PISTA TESTE DRIV2',
                        'PRECO'=>'916'),
                )

            ),
        1=>array(
                'IDDEPARTAMENTO'=>'0000000010',
                'DESCRDEPT'=>'Merch',
                'ITEM'=>
                array(
                    array(
                        'SETID'=>'RX',
                        'IDITEM'=>'000000000000002036',
                        'DESCRITEM'=>'PISTA TESTE DRIV23',
                        'PRECO'=>'200.78'),
                    array(
                        'SETID'=>'RX',
                        'IDITEM'=>'000000000000001608',
                        'DESCRITEM'=>'PISTA CRACHÁ  DRIV4',
                        'PRECO'=>'44341'),
                )                       
        ));

// solution
$newArr = array();
foreach ($yourArr as $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key => $innerVal) {
        if($key == 'ITEM'){
            foreach ($innerVal as $key_inner => $keyinner) {
                if(!empty($keyinner['IDITEM'])){
                    $newArr[$keyinner['IDITEM']] = $keyinner['PRECO'];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArr);
```

**Result values with IDITEM:**

```
Array
(
    [000000000000001367] => 1338.78
    [000000000000001925] => 916
    [000000000000002036] => 200.78
    [000000000000001608] => 44341
)
```